# Could this propeller work on a quadcopter and decrease the sound?

Tags: propeller, quadcopter

I came across a video yesterday that showcased a propeller design that looked very interesting. I am a regular drone flyer and I constantly look for exciting things to try out. Would this design in theory work and if so, would the sound of the propeller decrease by a lot? I was planning to 3d print them out and test them but i wanted to share the video with more experienced people first to see if i would waste my time or not/hurt the engines by using them.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdOiMQFgzD8)

My idea is to put it on my quadcopter that has 2300kv motors and works well with 5" props.

Comment: I love the description of the video on Youtube: `free green first ever world novelty perpetual best new car vehicles drone понтонни ВЕЦ`

Comment: Wow, a triplane propeller. Well, the propeller would kind of work, but not as well as a regular one.

Comment: 2300kv? As in kilovolts? Er...

Comment: Sound might decrease as much as the design lets you run the propeller at lower RPM for the desired loading. The efficiency is going to be definitely worse though.